# Get all child input elements of fieldsets with classname, input elements being only indirect children of fieldsets

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, xpages

I have an issue regarding some Client JS embedded on an XPage.
I want to get the elements shown in the picture with Javascript (DOM), and I am unable to set a classname to the Input directly because the "`</xp:checkBoxGroup>`" tag (in XPS) generates fieldsets and tables with the classname around the input instead of applying the classname directly to the input.

[image: image showing the html structure and elements I want]

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into CSS selectors again and found a selector that matches my needs:

```
    function getSelection(){
    var group = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked"); 
    return group;
}
```